# Using flow in javascript conflicts with Babel in class members

Tags: javascript, babeljs, flowtype

Im trying to get flow to work with babel. I ve got the following class

```
// @flow
    class Character{

    name = "";

    constructor(name){
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Not adding `name = "";` causes an error in flow. (Frankly im not sure why as you cant normally set a member in a js class like that at all ( unless its static ), i guess for type checking.)

The issue is that when i run babel to strip away all the flow stuff, i get this error :

```
SyntaxError: a.js: Unexpected token (9:8)
   7 | class Character{
   8 | 
>  9 |     name = "";
     |         ^
```

Any ideas why this is happening? Babel is properly configured with flow and **works otherwise**. The .babelrc is :

```
{
"presets": ["flow"]
}
```

Comment: Well as you said, "*you cant normally set a member in a js class like that at all*" (at least not in ES6, but there are proposals to allow this). Try a `name: string` declaration instead

Comment: Ok that works BUT why the heck would they allow for that in flow when it cant be stripped away afterwards? Astounding..

Thanks a lot however.

Comment: @GeorgeAvgoustis that can be stripped away, but it sounds like your current Babel configuration does not support it. Flow allows that syntax assuming your Babel transpiler *will* strip it

Comment: Hmm ok. I did download the latest one from npm so i assumed that would be enough but maybe i need to look further into it.